# PHP using include() variable scope issue

Tags: php

I have commonFun.php for commong functions;

```
<?php

function connectDB(){
    $con = @mysqli_connect( "localhost:3306", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "DogSport" ) or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
}

//check that email is not already in list
function emailChecker( $email ){
    connectDB();

    $safe_email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $email );
    $check_sql = "SELECT Id FROM Subscribers WHERE Email='". $safe_email. "'";

    $result = mysqli_query ( $con, $check_sql ) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

When I call emailChecker() function from another PHP script, why does $con variable in connectDB() is not available to emailChecker() function? I have already called connectDB() function inside emailChecker() function? What am I doing wrong?????

I get the following errors;

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\commonFun.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\commonFun.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\commonFun.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\commonFun.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\commonFun.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\commonFun.php on line 14
Couldn't execute SELECT query:
```

Comment: You're defining `$con` in `connectDB()` but not returning it, so as soon as the `connectDB()` function finishes executing, `$con` ceases to be in scope, and removed from memory

Comment: you can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Modify `connectDB()` to return the value of `$con` and modify `emailChecker()` to assign the response from `connectDB()`.... `$con = connectDB();`

Answer (score 1):

Bad solution but it will work:

```
function connectDB(){
    global $con;

    $con = @mysqli_connect( "localhost:3306", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "DogSport" ) or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
}

//check that email is not already in list
function emailChecker( $email ){
    global $con;

    connectDB();

    $safe_email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $email );
    $check_sql = "SELECT Id FROM Subscribers WHERE Email='". $safe_email. "'";

    $result = mysqli_query ( $con, $check_sql ) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Another solution:

```
$con = @mysqli_connect( "localhost:3306", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "DogSport" ) or die ("Couldn't connect to server");

//check that email is not already in list
function emailChecker( $email ){
    global $con;

    $safe_email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $email );
    $check_sql = "SELECT Id FROM Subscribers WHERE Email='". $safe_email. "'";

    $result = mysqli_query ( $con, $check_sql ) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));
}
```

It's bad to call mysqli_connect() in every function calls in your script. You must connect to the database only once every page executions.

Comment: Sir I understand your solution 2 very well. That is what I all know about global keyword which variables declared outside any function can be accessed inside function using global keyword. But I do not understand your solution 1 which it has no variable outside any function and why do you mention global keyword inside both functions? Thanks

Comment: If PHP is not strict (`error_reporting ^ E_STRICT`), you can globalize undefined variable without any errors. In solution 1, when you call `emailChecker()` function, it will call `connectDB()` inside which sets `$con` variable which were globalized already. Test it.

Answer (score -1):

function connectDB(){

$con = @mysqli_connect( "localhost:3306", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "DogSport" ) or        die ("Couldn't connect to server");

return  $con;
}

Comment: What does that mean? I am not using a class here, right?

Comment: use this code function always return value its helpful,,